# How to tell if a path is a file or a directory?

Tags: powershell, path, filesystems

**[tl;dr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read)**:

Given a filesystem path, how can I determine whether it refers to a file or a directory in PowerShell?

---

Firstly, I actually know pretty much nothing about Powershell so please excuse any ignorance I may display in this posting.

I am hoping to create a script which can trigger processes whenever changes occur in a monitored folder. I have found a Powershell script on the Internet which I think has given me a good head start. However, after adapting it a bit and testing it out I have discovered a problem with it.

The script basically creates and appends a log file of changes to the monitored folder and sub-folders and it seems to work well. However, if I make any changes inside a sub-folder, as well as recording those changes in the log file, it also adds a line to the log file stating that the sub-folder itself has changed, like as if it was a file that has changed.

I need the script to trigger a process whenever a file changes but it must not trigger an extra process in addition to the processes that are triggered by any changes inside a sub-folder. I hope you can understand what I am saying here.

I therefore need a way (which integrates well into the script that I have found) of distinguishing between when a file is changed and a folder is changed.

The script (which I have adapted a bit) is as follows:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "monitoredfolder"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = {
            $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $Name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
            $OldName = $Event.SourceEventArgs.OldName
            $OldFullPath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.OldFullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $OldFullPath, $path, $OldName, $Name"
            Add-content "log.txt" -value $logline
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I am hoping to be able to add a line to the $action section which would create another variable which can be added as a column in the log file. Based purely on guesswork, I have tried the following and others but they did not work:

```
$pathtype = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPathType

$pathAttributes = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPathAttributes

$Attributes = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Attributes

$IsDirectory = $Event.SourceEventArgs.IsDirectory
```

To be honest, I did not really expect them to work but I thought I would give them a go.

Does anyone here know all of the things which can go after the second dot in "$Event.SourceEventArgs."?

Is there another approach I should be taking?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see the link in the update I just made (hope that's OK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Test-Path -Type Leaf -LiteralPath $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
```

tells you whether path string `$Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath` refers to an (existing) *file*, as opposed to a *directory* (`-Type Container`).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this it is with [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) and the [Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists) static method.

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists($Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)
```

I've found it to be roughly 4 times faster than Test-Path when benchmarked for not much more typing.

To answer your other question: `Does anyone here know all of the things which can go after the second dot in "$Event.SourceEventArgs."?` you can easily find out what properties and methods are available on an object by sending it to [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member).

Changing your action to

```
$action = {
            $Event.SourceEventArgs | Get-Member
          }
```

and then retrieving the output from the created job will list the properties, methods, and type of object.

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
3      fe46cc0b-51e...                 NotStarted    False                                ...                      



PS> Get-Job 3 | Receive-Job -Keep


   TypeName: System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs

Name        MemberType Definition                                    
----        ---------- ----------                                    
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()                             
GetType     Method     type GetType()                                
ToString    Method     string ToString()                             
ChangeType  Property   System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes ChangeType {get;}
FullPath    Property   string FullPath {get;}                        
Name        Property   string Name {get;}
```